# Is it possible to get a running UEFI system with stock Qemu and OVMF on 19.10?

Tags: uefi, 19.10, qemu

It seems terribly complicated compared to running a legacy BIOS machine where it basically runs out of the box. Now I've reached a point where I'm wondering if it's not broken on 19.10 in that respect.

Last thing I tried (and most promising I was thinking) :

`qemu-system-x86_64 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=fbios.bin -enable-kvm -cpu max -cdrom ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso -m 4G`

Where `fbios.bin` is a writable copy of `/usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd`

But I only get `Guest has not initialized the display (yet).`, and the CPU goes 100%, apparently doing... nothing.

I tried passing `-device qxl-vga` too, with the same abysmally inefficient result.

Advices, anyone ? Or should I better stick with machines from the last decade ?

Answer (score 0):

See this GitHub repo [OSX-KVM](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM) for a QEMU UEFI bootloader. They use it to load Clover (and hence MacOS), but you can find the OVMF file that you need there. Alternatively, you can build your own EDK2 as shown in [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/EDK2).